# Select only newest records in same table that repeats

Tags: sql

I have two tables borrow and books. I need to select only free books. 
The problem is when one book is borrowed several times, then in my code select  always gives me that the book is available, but she is borrowed again and should be unavailable.
Im using MS SQL Server 2012 Express with SQL Server Management.

```
CREATE VIEW Free_Books AS

select distinct ID_book, Name_book, FirstName_writer, LastName_writer from Books

left join borrow on books.ID_book = borrow.ID_book

where date_borrow IS NOT NULL and date_returned IS NOT NULL 

or 
date_borrow is NULL and date_returned IS NULL
```

Comment: Please also tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help a lot.

Comment: I have a feeling your WHERE clause is causing these issues - from the way you have it separated out on different lines it looks like they should be grouped together on each line. When you mix all those ANDs and ORs without grouping you won't get the results you're looking for. If you can post some sample data/schemas someone can give you a better answer.

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 Express with SQL Server Managment. Thank you for all coments, and i'm sory for lack of information, this is my first post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, you need to first get a list of only the most recent borrow, then only show those that have not yet been returned. This should work in SQL Server and some other databases, but as @Mihai mentioned, we can help more if we know what system you're using:

```
CREATE VIEW Free_Books
AS

WITH ListAll
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
            ID_book
           ,Name_book
           ,FirstName_writer
           ,LastName_writer
           ,date_borrow
           ,date_returned
           ,datum_borrow
           ,datum_returned
           ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID_book ORDER BY date_borrow DESC /* this is the most recent borrow */)
    FROM    Books
            LEFT JOIN borrow ON books.ID_book = borrow.ID_book
    )
SELECT ID_book
    ,Name_book
    ,FirstName_writer
    ,LastName_Writer
FROM ListAll
WHERE ListAll.RowNum = 1 /* eliminate prior borrows */
    AND date_borrow IS NOT NULL
    AND date_returned IS NOT NULL
    OR datum_borrow IS NULL
    AND datum_returned IS NULL;
```

[Added due to subsequent questions]

Personally, I would include all books in your view but add an [IsAvailable] boolean flag:

```
CREATE VIEW All_Books
AS

WITH ListAll
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
            ID_book
           ,Name_book
           ,FirstName_writer
           ,LastName_writer
           ,datum_borrow
           ,datum_returned
           ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID_book ORDER BY date_borrow DESC /* this is the most recent borrow */)
    FROM    Books
            LEFT JOIN borrow ON books.ID_book = borrow.ID_book
    )
SELECT ID_book
    ,Name_book
    ,FirstName_writer
    ,LastName_Writer
    ,[IsAvailable] = CAST(CASE WHEN datum_borrow IS NOT NULL AND datum_returned IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT)
FROM ListAll
WHERE ListAll.RowNum = 1 /* Only the most recent record per book */;
```

You wouldn't want a database trigger because that would only fire once someone tried to borrow a book: that's not very good customer service. Ideally, your front end application would show all books, but with the ones already borrowed in a different color (usually gray). Then the customer sees what books exist as well as which are available now.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This works for me, but one question when i try to use all ID_book result always gives me last record, but the result should be nothing. And my mistake date_borrow is the same as datum_borrow and date_returned is the same as datum_returned i translate name of variable to make it easier to understand.

Comment: And i forget to ask, how can i make trigger with same conditions to avoid borrowing book which is already borrowed?

Comment: Even now with new code in variable 'IsAvailable' the last book is always available. Im connecting database to access for gui, i hink its litter slower when i use the view then with query select only free books and then use that select for drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to tell without seeing your table structure, but it looks to me like your current query is joining on all of the past "borrow" events for a given book rather than just checking to see if it has been returned since the latest time it was borrowed. I think you should try writing a subquery that selects only the row with the latest borrow date for a given book id. Then you can add that to your query for the sake of checking whether a book has been returned or not.

Comment: I have two tables books and borrow, in book i have (ID_book, Name_book, FirstName_writer, LastName_writer etc), in borrow i have (ID_borrow, ID_book, date_borrow, date_returned) they are connected over ID_book) . I need to select ID_book, Name_book, FirstName_writer, LastName_Write when book is free (that includes if shes never borrowed and if she is borrowed and returned.                      I hope u got it :)

Answer (score 0):

It works! @RussellFox code is good! I had wrong type of variable... when i set datum_borrow and datum_returned as datetime it worked like swiss clock :) 
Thanks everyone for help!